# Jenkins Groovy: How do we add 'Execute a Windows batch command' in groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, groovy-console

I see that there is a '**shell()**' equivalent in groovy script for 'Execute shell command' option in Job UI.
What is the equivalent for 'Execute a Windows Batch command'?

P.S. Not looking for :

def process='xxxx'.execute()as it does not work on the slave I am triggering on. Any alternatives?

Comment: why you dont want to use execute()?

Answer (score 2):

Major dupe, but just in case someone trips over this one first...

any windows batch file cannot be run directly, pass it to cmd.exe with the /k or /c switch (iirc)

something like "cmd.exe /c myBatchFile.bat".execute()